# How to build a reactive application using React Query and Spring Webflux

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-webflux, react-query

My frontend is written in React using React Query, while I use Spring Webflux as my backend. I created a dashboard in React and I want the data that gets populated in the dashboard to come in real time so that the user doesn't have to refresh. Multiple users will be logged into this dashboard and will have access to the same data thus the need to show real time data. In order to accomplish this, do I need a WebSocket in both my backend and frontend to achieve this? Or does only my frontend need a WebSocket? Or do I even need a WebSocket at all? There isn't much documentation about this. Ideally bidirectional communication is what I want, however, sending messages from my backend to my frontend will also suffice.